# How to use register_namespace multiple times for same URL with different "anchor tag"?

Tags: python, namespaces, elementtree

I am updating an xml file and want to preserve multiple namespaces with same URI but different anchor tag using `ET.register_namespace`

Following code is what I've tried :

```
ET.register_namespace('', "http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5")
ET.register_namespace('', "http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows")
ET.register_namespace('', "http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent")

ns = "{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}"
f = open ("def_ex.xml","ra")
tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

for defn in root.iter('%stag' %ns): 
    if "patch" in defn.get("class"): #pick id attrib where class attrib is "patch"
       print defn.get("id")       
       mirr_def = copy.deepcopy(defn)
       defn.append(mirr_def)
       tree.write("def_ex.xml")
       exit()
```

But the problem is `third` namespace is overwriting `one` and `two` as shown in the following output of the code:

```
<ns0:tag>
.......
.......
</ns0:tag>

<ns1:tag1>
........
........
</ns1:tag1>

<tag2>
......
......
</tag2>
```

My final question is how to preserve all namespaces without overwriting each other when there are different "anchor tags" with same URI ?

**Updated: def_ex.xml**

```
<oval_definitions xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns:oval-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5" xmlns:windows-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows" xmlns:independent-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows windows-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent independent-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5 oval-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd">
<tag id="oval:def:1" class="inventory">
...........
...........
...........
</tag>
<tag1 xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows" id="oval:tst:1" version="1">
............
............
</tag1>
<tag2 xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent" id="oval:tst:2" version="1">
............
............
</tag2>
</oval_definitions>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. "multiple namespaces with same URI" sounds strange. If the URI is the same, the namespace is the same. Also please show us the contents of def_ex.xml.

Comment: Yes, same URI with different anchor tags as shown in my code and def_ex.xml is huge file (over 2000 lines)

Comment: Please show us a trimmed down sample of the input XML and what you want the output to look like. And what is "anchor" tag?

Comment: I updated my question. ```anchor``` : it comes after ```#``` in an URI

Comment: What you call "anchor tag" is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Answer (score 2):

As [@mu 無](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25605905/3968498) has said, you will not be able to achieve what you want using *register_namespace* which explicitly guards against having duplicate prefixes.

I am not sure whether what you are trying to do is legal XML or supported by the library, but one way that might achieve what you want is to implement the [behaviour](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l1066) of *register_namespace* directly:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree._namespace_map[uri] = prefix # Replace uri and prefix.
```

And as a function (modified from original python library [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py)):

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree

def register_namespace(prefix, uri):
    if re.match("ns\d+$", prefix):
        raise ValueError("Prefix format reserved for internal use")
    xml.etree.ElementTree._namespace_map[uri] = prefix
```

I do **not** recommend doing this because it could break the library elsewhere in unexpected ways.

*Disclaimer: My code has not been tested.*

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same prefix to define all the 3 URIs. As mentioned in the docs, the namespace registry is global, and hence the values are being overwritten.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace):

> `xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix, uri)`
>
> Registers a namespace prefix. *The registry is global*, and any existing mapping for either the given prefix or the namespace URI will be removed. prefix is a namespace prefix. uri is a namespace uri. Tags and attributes in this namespace will be serialized with the given prefix, if at all possible.

I would suggest you to add namespaces for each of the URI's as follow, and use them accordingly

```
namespaces = {'ns1': 'http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5',
              'ns2': 'http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows',
              'ns3': 'http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent'}

for prefix, uri in namespaces.items():
    ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
```

Comment: Your solution appends corresponding prefixes to respective tags. But I want tags without prefix and preserving ```xmlns``` attribute in ```tag1``` and ```tag2```

Comment: @Kumarswamy I'm not able to understand your question exactly, can you give an exmaple of what output you are expecting? Just add three sections in your question - 1)Current Input 2)Current output 3)Expected output. It would be even better if you could share the raw input xml using pastebin or gist

Comment: this answer is opposite to the question.